# Android. Как запустить In App Billing из собственного класса?

Tags: android, java

Подскажите, как запустить сервис внутренних платежей `Google Play` из собственного класса?
Сервис необходимо внедрить в игру, состоящую из одной активити. Все экраны игры - экземпляры класса `Screen`, который в свою очередь является наследником класса `AndroidGame`, а уже он в свою очередь наследником `Activity`. Ошибки возникают в методах `Billing` сервиса.
Ранее подключал сервис в приложениях, в коде класса активити. Никаких проблем не возникало.

Если не сталкивались с `In App Billing`, подскажите, как запустить активити из собственного класса? Готов уже создать отдельное активити под обработку запросов на покупку контента, но опять же возникает проблема старта этой активити из собственного класса.
Не работает:

```
Intent intent_start = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BillingActivity.class);
startActivity(intent_start);
```

Comment: запустить активити можно с помощью контекста  
context.startActivity(YOU_INTENT) => собственно чтобы запустить из своего класса, нужно передать туда контекст

Comment: вы немного не правильно передаете `context` приложения. нужно делать либо `Intent intent_start = new Intent(MyClass.this, BillingActivity.class);`, либо `Intent intent_start = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BillingActivity.class);`.

Comment: ваш собственный класс не является наследником активити? если нет, тогда нужно передать в него контекст. можно таким образом поступить, если собственный класс не наследник активити http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы. Проблема запуска активити решена.
В классе, наследуемом от активити добавляем:
public static Context context;
В onCreate: context = getBaseContext();
Далее:
public static Context getContext() {
    return context;
}
А в собственном классе для вызова активити набираем:
Context context = AndroidGame.getContext();
Intent intent_start = new Intent(context, BillingActivity.class);
intent_start.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent_start);